# GridFS creates infinite number of chunks and eats entire disk

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

We have an app that uploads files into GridFS using Java driver. During 6 months of app running in production we encountered situation, when MongoDB database grown up to entire disk (1TB in size ... database is 30GB in size ... so huge increase in size). By investigating the reason we found out, that we have 20M fs.chunks for one file and that eat the disk. Second time(just a few days ago) it created 40M chunks for one file and crashed with disk full message. There is no fs.file record for these chunks, so we can't see details.

There was MongoDB 3.2.5 running on server so we upgraded to latest 3.4.4 version. But generaly, is there any known issue we should we aware of? Is there a way how to configure MongoDB to not create such huge files (some limit of number of chunks per file or something) ?

EDIT #1 - Additional details

- fs.files count: 7800 (average, we delete old files, new files are uploaded each day)
- average file size: users store common MS Office file, 60-100kB, we have a several bigger files around 100MB.

Users are uploading files using web interface where there is a limit on upload size. So nobody can upload 900GB file ... I doubt anybody has one ... 
Also no rename in collection or any database maintenance during a time, app is working seamlessly.

Comment: What are you actually storing in GridFS? How big are the "files" supposed to be on average? How many "files" to you expect to be storing? What is the current count in `fs.files` or whatever the collection has been renamed. So the files collection and not the chunks. So that's a few things you can be looking at and then add the information to your question if you cannot see the conclusion I'm drawing to.

Comment: Updated my post. When it happended a first time we took this as an anomaly. But it happened second time a few days ago and huge problem is that it eats disk and to do anything with 1TB database is quite slow, its problem to remove bad chunks and repair db as it requires free space to shrink database etc.

Comment: For starters if your average size is consitently under 16MB, then you probably should not have been using GridFS. If you wanted it in MongoDB and not a filesystem then a regular document property with binary data would have saved you a lot of grief. The point I wanted to get at with the volume is the consideration that you might very well have a logic failure and you are actually creating new files/chunks when things are actually being updated. Again, misuse of the API could easily be leaving orphaned chunks as well.

Comment: So the general "small files" would seem to say that GridFS should not be used here. Much catering for the difference of twitter traffic to your own to say Justin Bieber, then your 100MB files should be the "edge case", where there are "special considerations" for that usage and you deal with that "small number" differently than you deal with the majority.

Comment: I see your point about the API usage etc. but everything is working fine on thousands of files ... with no problem. My question was mainly whether anyone encoutered such behaviour, if there is any protection on MongoDB side or if there was such bug in some older versions on MongoDB (see info about upgrade). We just tried eliminate MongoDB issues. Meanwhile we are investigating our code to remove potential bugs.

Comment: I would not be looking at "behavior" and would be more or less looking at the "implemented code" where you are calling GridFS methods. I'm also really not sure that you are understanding that there really is no such thing as "GridFS" anyway. To the database, this means nothing, and is just collections and documents. GridFS is a "driver" concept, and therefore "issues" would be very specific to the "driver implementation" and only then likely with a specific version. But again, it's far more plausible your own usage of the API has caused the issued explained here.